# How to go from instances to core data?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I am new to iOS programming and this is the first app I've ever made. Basically I did not know about core data when making this app so I made the classes normally. My app is basically a to-do list app with Tasks as objects that enter the taskArray (array that acts as data source to TableViewController). The tasks are entered to the taskArray by users. I just have one question when migrating from objects that are erased when the app closes to core data: Should I delete my Task class and remake it as an entity in Core Data? If so, would it be possible to add the objects I make with Core Data to the taskArray or would I have to completely remodel my whole app and cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Here is some of my code:

Tasks.h

```
@interface Tasks : NSObject <NSCoding>{
    NSDateComponents *conversionInfo;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *taskName;
@property NSTimeInterval timeInterval;
@property NSDate *dateCreated;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval timeIntervalInMinutes;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval timeIntervalInHours;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *timeIntervalString;
@end
```

Tasks.m

```
@implementation Tasks
@synthesize taskName, timeInterval, dateCreated;
-(id) init{
    if (self)
    {
    self.taskName = taskName;
    self.timeInterval = timeInterval;
        self.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }
    return self;
}
-(NSString *)timeIntervalString{
    NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *date1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:timeInterval sinceDate:date];
    unsigned int unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
    conversionInfo = [sysCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date  toDate:date1  options:0];
    if ([conversionInfo hour] == 0){
        if ([conversionInfo minute] == 1) {
            _timeIntervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d MIN", [conversionInfo minute]];
        } else {
            _timeIntervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d MINS", [conversionInfo minute]];
        }
    } else if ([conversionInfo hour] == 1) {
        if ([conversionInfo minute] == 0){
        _timeIntervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d HR", [conversionInfo hour]];
     } else if ([conversionInfo minute] == 1) {
    _timeIntervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d HR %d MIN", [conversionInfo hour], [conversionInfo minute]];
     } else {
     _timeIntervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d HR %d MINS", [conversionInfo hour], [conversionInfo minute]];
     }
    } else {
        if ([conversionInfo minute] == 0) {
         _timeIntervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d HRS ", [conversionInfo hour]];
        } else if ([conversionInfo minute] == 1){
            _timeIntervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d HRS %d MIN", [conversionInfo hour], [conversionInfo minute]];
        } else {
        _timeIntervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d HRS %d MINS", [conversionInfo hour], [conversionInfo minute]];
        }
    }
    return _timeIntervalString;
}
@end
```

TableViewController.m

```
-(NSMutableArray *)taskArray {
    if (!taskArray) {
        taskArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return taskArray;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 cellSubclassCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (!cell)
        cell = [[cellSubclassCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    if([indexPath section] == 0){
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName] uppercaseString];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];
        cell.imageView.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedhighlighted.png"];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:236.0/255 green:240.0/255 blue:241.0/255 alpha:1.0f]];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = baseColor;

        NSString *detailText = [[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] timeIntervalString];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = detailText;
               [[cell detailTextLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Black" size:12]];
        [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-DemiBold" size:16]];
[cell.contentView setAlpha:1];
    } else if ([indexPath section] == 1) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName] uppercaseString];

     cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:236.0/255 green:240.0/255 blue:241.0/255 alpha:1.0f]];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = baseColor;
        NSString *detailText = [[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] timeIntervalString];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = detailText;
        [[cell detailTextLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Black" size:12]];
        [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-DemiBold" size:16]];
        [cell.contentView setAlpha:0.5];
    }
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlechecking:)];
    //cell.contentView
    [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    return cell;
    }
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    Tasks *task = [[Tasks alloc]init];
    if (indexPath.section == 0){
    task.taskName = [[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName];
        task.timeInterval = [[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] timeInterval];
    task.dateCreated = [[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] dateCreated];
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1){
        task.taskName = [[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName];
        task.timeInterval = [[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] timeInterval];
        task.dateCreated = [[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] dateCreated];
    }
    DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
    [dvc setTestTask:task];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I delete my Task class and remake it as an entity in Core Data?

It may be simpler to change `Task` so that it's a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, create your model, and set `Task` as the class for the task entity in your model. You'll still need to do some work to convert your app to Core Data, but whatever logic you've created for your task class can still be useful.

Answer (score 0):

As a novice I'd also recommend you check out Core Data frameworks such as the Sensible TableView framework. Saves me tons of development time when working with Core Data.